# php DOM inner TAG ( simple_html_dom )

Tags: php, dom, tags, simple-html-dom

I have this html:
    `<h2><a href="http://.... > title</h2>`
How can I get the string "href"?

I tried with:

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://...');

foreach($html->find('h2')->find('a') as $k) {
echo $k->href . '<br>';
}
```

error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object

Comment: just try to remove first 'h2' find creteria and apply for all 'a' that is $html->find('a')..I think it will work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not used PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser...but I think the error could be because it returns you a string and you are applying the find function on that returned string which is expecting a html object to be passed...

The previous solution is wrong bcz it just searched for a string while find function searches a tag..

One possible way is what I have commented..
remove first 'h2' find creteria and apply for all 'a' that is

```
foreach($html->find('a') as $k) {
echo $k->href . '<br>';
}
```

Other possible solution is use php inbuild file_get_contents and seach by regular 
expressions...I have done that for you...

```
$html = file_get_contents('new.php');
$reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";
$uql=array();
preg_match($reg_exUrl, $html, $url);

print_r($url);
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using two `->find()` calls, try

```
foreach($html->find('h2 > a') as $k) {
```

I haven't used Simple DOM myself, so I'm not sure if selectors work or not. If not, try

```
foreach($html->find('a') as $k) {
```

and sort through the results.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately the error ( Call to a member function find() on a non-object ) still exists

Comment: @LucaZap Oh wait, you're using the Simple HTML DOM, not the official [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php). Never mind then.